# invalid hash key (facebook login integration)

Tags: android, facebook, hash, authentication

first of all: I've tried all purposed solutions up here on stackexchange. Not one worked so far.

So here's my problem:

I try to integrate a facebook login in my android app. I can “log in” at the first try (I get the opportunity to log in, but nothing happens). When I try it again, I get the following error:
“invalid key hash. the key hash does not match any stored key hashes”

What I’ve done:

- Implement all steps of the developer.facebook tutorial to get the login button
- Create a development key (keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%PATH%\debug.keystore" | "%PATH%\openssl" sha1 -binary |"%PATH%\openssl" base64) and added it
- Create a release key (keytool -exportcert -alias android -keystore "%PATH%\debug.keystore" | "%PATH%\openssl" sha1 -binary |"%PATH%\openssl" base64) and added it
- When I add my package name and my class name, I get the following message:
  “We were unable to verify your package namecom.example.facebooklogin on Google Play. Please double-check your package name before proceeding.
  If your app is not publicly listed on Google Play yet, you may safely ignore this warning.” – I ignore the message, because my app isn’t at google play (it’s my first testgame)

I’ve added this part in my onCreate, but nothing changes:

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.kndel.facebooklogin",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

What’s wrong?? I have no idea

Comment: Please paste your activity class  where you using above code

Answer (score 0):

Add this function into your class,and call this function in oncreate methode,then generate **signed apk** (this function will return hash key for both mode bedbug and release) and run sign apk in your device and check log-cat, copy generated hash key to facebook developer console.

```
private void showHashKey()
{
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.kisan.kisan",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }

}
```

**Note : This function will return hash key for both mode bedbug and release.**

Check facebook authentication,it will work fine